# How do I install Odoo All-in-one (ERP, CRM) management software

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, apache2, nginx, odoo

I installed Odoo with the help of http://www.gotodoo.com. After the installation of Odoo 9.5 in Ubuntu 16.04, while running `localhost:8069` in the browser it returns:

```
500 Internal server error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. 
Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

[image]

How do I install Odoo on my Ubuntu?

Comment: This is the output of sudo systemctl status odooo                               doo.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: everything is working well   but I installed first time odoo in my pc and got this problem so i need somehelp

Comment: ok  I am waiting your reply even success or not and thanks for helping me

Answer (score 2):

### How to install [Odoo 11 All-in-one management software](https://www.odoo.com/) on Ubuntu

---

#### 1. Install Odoo

- Here are presented two alternative methods of Odos's installation - from the GitHib project and from the repository.

---

**1.A** **[Install Odoo from the repository](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/setup/install.html). This should be the preferable way**.

Install the dependencies, add the repository and its key, update the system and install the package:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install postgresql
wget -O - https://nightly.odoo.com/odoo.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://nightly.odoo.com/11.0/nightly/deb/ ./" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/odoo.list
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt install odoo
```

With this configuration you can control the service by the commands:

```
sudo systemctl status odoo.service
sudo systemctl restart odoo.service
sudo systemctl start odoo.service
sudo systemctl stop odoo.service
```

The main configuration file is: `/etc/odoo/odoo.conf`.

---

**1.B** **[Install Odoo from the GitHib project](https://github.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript).** **If you've followed 1.A skip this step - go to 2.**

This section uses [Yenthe V.G](https://github.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript)'s installation scrip. I found this approach in the article: [Install Odoo 11 on Ubuntu 16.04...](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-odoo-11-on-ubuntu-16-04/). 
Download [`odoo_install.sh`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript/10.0/odoo_install.sh):

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript/11.0/odoo_install.sh
```

Edit `odoo_install.sh` and modify the parameters, under the section `#fixed parameters`:

- `OE_USER` will be the username for the system user, the default one is `odoo`.
- By default the script will create user's home directory `/<odoo user>`. You could leave the following values as default, but I would prefer `/home/<odoo user>`:

  ```
  OE_HOME="/home/$OE_USER"
  OE_HOME_EXT="$OE_HOME/${OE_USER}-server"
  ```
- `INSTALL_WKHTMLTOPDF` set to False if you do not want to install Wkhtmltopdf, if you want to install it you should set it to `True`.
- `OE_PORT` is the port where Odoo should run on, for example `8069`.
- `OE_VERSION` is the Odoo version to install, for example `11.0` for Odoo V11.
- `IS_ENTERPRISE` will install the Enterprise version on top of 11.0 if you set it to `True`, set it to `False` if you want the community version of Odoo 11.
- `OE_SUPERADMIN` is the master password for this Odoo installation. The default pass is `admin`.

Make `odoo_install.sh` executable and execute it as *root*:

```
chmod +x odoo_install.sh && sudo ./odoo_install.sh
```

You could control the application by the commands:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/odoo-server restart
sudo /etc/init.d/odoo-server start
sudo /etc/init.d/odoo-server stop
```

The configuration file is: `/etc/odoo-server.conf`.

---

#### 2. Proceed the installation of ODOO through [a supported web browser](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/setup/deploy.html#supported-browsers)

[image]

---

#### 3. Reverse proxy

In order to access your Odoo application only by using your domain name, without the port number in the URL, or through HTTPS, you need to set up a reverse proxy:

- To use **Apache** as Reverse proxy - follow step 7 from the article [Install Odoo 11 on Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache as a Reverse Proxy](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-odoo-11-on-ubuntu-16-04/).
- To use **Nginx** as Reverse proxy - follow the Section [HTTPS from the Odoo's  documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/setup/deploy.html#https).
- `stunnel4` also could be applicable...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a bash script to easily install Odoo.

## Installation procedure

### 1. Download the script:

`sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript/11.0/odoo_install.sh`

### 2. Modify the parameters as you wish.

There are a few things you can configure, this is the most used list:

`OE_USER` will be the username for the system user.
`INSTALL_WKHTMLTOPDF` set to `False`if you do not want to install `Wkhtmltopdf`, if you want to install it you should set it to `True`.

`OE_PORT` is the port where Odoo should run on, for example 8069.

`OE_VERSION` is the Odoo version to install, for example `11.0` for Odoo V11.

`IS_ENTERPRISE` will install the Enterprise version on top of `11.0` if you set it to `True`, set it to `False` if you want the community version of Odoo 11.

`OE_SUPERADMIN`is the master password for this Odoo installation.

### 3. Make the script executable

`sudo chmod +x odoo_install.sh`

### 4. Execute the script:

`sudo ./odoo_install.sh`

Useful commands:

Start odoo server

`sudo /etc/init.d/odoo-server start`

Restart odoo server

`sudo /etc/init.d/odoo-server restart`

Stop odoo server

`sudo /etc/init.d/odoo-server stop`

If you want to see more helpful commands run:
`sudo /etc/init.d/odoo-server -h`